# Canada immigration

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada

We are planning to migrate and settle in Canada, however,I have doubt that , If become the primary applicant, my husband will be allowed to work in Canada or not?

Comment: Why do you have this doubt?

Comment: Does his profession require a license, such as engineering or medicine?

Answer (score 1):

If you apply to the skilled worker program then yes, both of you receive a permanent residence that allows you to work.

If it's another type of visa, you have to check on http://www.cic.gc.ca/ for the conditions.